# how to manage and monitor websocket connections - nodejs

Tags: node.js, websocket, monitoring, pm2

i'm going to make websocket connection to third party's websocket server on behalf of user in nodejs (imagine i have 100 users)

i want to save and monitor this connections and keep them alive permanently until i close them

i tried to create these connection in other js files and run them via pm2 and pass the configs by arguments to file, like below:

`pm2.start({ script:` ~/project/websocket.js`, name: "user 1", args:` ${userId}`, })`

but i think this is not a safe and robust solution
what you guys suggest me to do?
thanks

Comment: Did you search for relevant solutions? What is your current implementation, what did you try ? Please read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example